# {error,{not_started,ibrowse}} when using couchbeam

Tags: erlang, couchdb, ubuntu-11.10

by this document http://benoitc.github.com/couchbeam/

```
application:start(sasl),
application:start(ibrowse),
application:start(couchbeam).
```

When I run the code, it shows:

```
=PROGRESS REPORT==== 1-Mar-2012::10:16:57 ===
         application: crypto
          started_at: nonode@nohost
{error,{not_started,ibrowse}}
```

I want to do know how to make `application:start(ibrowse),`work, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works by `erl -pz ibrowse/ebin/`

Answer (score 0):

According to your error message "started_at: nonode@nohost", I think that it may be caused by your erlang configuration file error.
Have you set up ".erlang.cookie" file, and is the file owner mode is exclusive? Only owner is allowed to read or write?
You can check your problem by inputting the command "erl -sname aaa"? Is output "nonode@nohost"?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with:

```
erl -pa ebin -pa deps/ibrowse/ebin -s couchbeam
```